# Lubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: lubuntu

I am very interested with Lubuntu, and just have a few questions. If I install Lubuntu 16.04, will I be able to do all of the following just as I do in Ubuntu 14.04?

1. Mount/unmount flash drives via GParted/Thunar?
2. Compile C++, Java, Python, etc. programs via terminal with Makefiles?
3. Use the default note pad (text editor) to write programs in the above programming languages?

(Sorry if this question seems ignorant/noobish, I just want to be sure that I can do these tasks before installing the OS)

Thank you!

Comment: will you wait for saying yes you can !! please explain what is the question / questions !!

Comment: 1) Why do you want to use GParted to mount/unmount flash drives? 2) Leafpad won't do syntax highlighting. However, it's trivial to install Geany or Mousepad or even Gedit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You mount/unmount flash drives using the default Lubuntu file manager PcManFM, but yeah.
2. Yes.  Terminal works just like any other Linux distro.
3. Yes.  The default is leafpad, but you can install any other one you like.

*BUT* - don't take my word for it.  Boot into a live USB of Lubuntu and see for yourself!  It won't affect your PC at all and you can try out all the things you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do everything you can in Ubuntu 16.04. Lubuntu is just Ubuntu with the LXDE desktop environment. Personally, I sometimes prefer LXDE. LXDE is lightweight too so it may be faster.

Comment: BTW, you are not a noob

Answer (score -1):

I think that as Lubuntu uses the same repositories as Ubuntu you should be able to install whatever you want. I think it is a good approach to start light and add what you really want. I think you should also look at [peppermint 6](https://peppermintos.com/2015/05/peppermint-six-is-here/) and [puppy](http://puppylinux.com/)